# Prism IDisposable Autofac and Lifetime Scope

Tags: prism

I am using Prism to navigate between views in my WPF application.  One view in particular I've implemented with the IRegionMemberLifetime.KeepAlive => returns false; to create a new instance of the view every time we navigate to the view (we need to do this for display reasons).  This view also hosts a custom win32 control that I need to do some cleanup in using IDisposable.Dispose.  When I navigate to my view and then away from it, I'd expect Dispose to get called (to run cleanup).  I was able to achieve this by implementing a custom region behavior as discussed here, https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/7.  All this is working fine except everything gets marked for disposal but the GC doesn't actually get rid of anything.  I'm using Autofac as my IOC container and after doing some research I've concluded the reason comes down to Autofac and lifetime scopes of IDisposables, https://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/.  Basically Autofac holds references to the IDisposable and the GC won't get rid of the old view because of this.  For instance I'm registering my view in the Module as _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation();  I'm not able to register this with any sort of lifetime and I'm not sure how I'd resolve this with a lifetime specified?  When I call RegionManager.RequestNavigate I don't see any sort of overloads to specify lifetime?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterTypeForNavigation` essentially does `builder.RegisterType(type).Named<object>(name);` which you can do yourself, too, of course and apply any lifetime you desire. There's no magic in registering for navigation, `RegisterTypeForNavigation` is just a shorthand.

To make Autofac ignore the `IDisposable`s, one can write

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeView>().Named<object>(typeof(SomeView).Name).ExternallyOwned();
```

From [the docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#disabling-disposal):

> **Disabling Disposal**
>
> Components are owned by the container by default and will be disposed by it when  appropriate. To disable this, register a component as having external ownership:
>
> `builder.RegisterType<SomeComponent>().ExternallyOwned();`
>
> The container will never call `Dispose()` on an object registered with external ownership. It is up to you to dispose of components registered in this fashion.

Comment: So I didn't know this, and I tried implementing the registration this way, but it still didn't help.  Even if I register the view as .InstancePerDependency(); Autofac won't ever release of the view because when I call RequestNavigate() I assume the view is being resolved under the same lifetime scope.  I'd need to somehow call RequestNavigate() and have that resolve the view under a new lifetime scope.

Comment: For the view model, you could set a new factory in the `ViewModelLocationProvider`. For the view, you can provide your own `RegionNavigationContentLoader` and override `CreateNewRegionItem`.

Answer (score 0):

So extending @Haukinger answer.  This is what finally worked for me:

```
//builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SomeView>();
builder.RegisterType<SomeView>().Named<object> 
(typeof(SomeView).Name).ExternallyOwned();
```

That ExternallyOwned() signals to autofac that the user is going to handle calling dispose and that autofac shouldn't track the IDisposable.